# Error on Ofbiz startup

Tags: java, apache, ant, rmi, ofbiz

I have a problem when I try to start my ofbiz-application. I ran `ant configure` and `ant clean build`. But when I try to execute the `startofbiz.sh`-script I get this exception:

```
2017-08-21 14:00:20,614 (main) [  GenericDispatcher.java:69 :INFO ]      Creating new dispatcher [RMIDispatcher] (main)
org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException: Cannot start() org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RmiServiceContainer (Unable to bind RMIDispatcher to RMI on //host[127.0.0.1]:port[1099]/name[RMIDispatcher] - with remote=RemoteDispatcherImpl[UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.202.100.143:53479,org.ofbiz.service.rmi.socket.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory@28daffb4,org.ofbiz.service.rmi.socket.ssl.SSLClientSocketFactory@74485fa2](local),objID:[2a32fb17:15e04aa3f7e:-7fff, 5866446068611712226]]]] (RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)))
        at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:232)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:363)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:338)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:140)
org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerException: Unable to bind RMIDispatcher to RMI on //host[127.0.0.1]:port[1099]/name[RMIDispatcher] - with remote=RemoteDispatcherImpl[UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.202.100.143:53479,org.ofbiz.service.rmi.socket.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory@28daffb4,org.ofbiz.service.rmi.socket.ssl.SSLClientSocketFactory@74485fa2](local),objID:[2a32fb17:15e04aa3f7e:-7fff, 5866446068611712226]]]] (RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled))
        at org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RmiServiceContainer.start(RmiServiceContainer.java:142)
        at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:230)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:363)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:338)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:140)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:160)
        at org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RmiServiceContainer.start(RmiServiceContainer.java:140)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:393)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
        at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        ... 17 more
org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerException: Unable to bind RMIDispatcher to RMI on //host[127.0.0.1]:port[1099]/name[RMIDispatcher] - with remote=RemoteDispatcherImpl[UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[10.202.100.143:53479,org.ofbiz.service.rmi.socket.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory@28daffb4,org.ofbiz.service.rmi.socket.ssl.SSLClientSocketFactory@74485fa2](local),objID:[2a32fb17:15e04aa3f7e:-7fff, 5866446068611712226]]]] (RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled))
        at org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RmiServiceContainer.start(RmiServiceContainer.java:142)
        at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.start(ContainerLoader.java:230)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.startStartLoaders(Start.java:363)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:338)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:140)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:160)
        at org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RmiServiceContainer.start(RmiServiceContainer.java:140)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ofbiz.service.rmi.RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:393)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
        at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        ... 17 more
java.lang.Exception: Error during start.
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.start(Start.java:342)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:140)
```

The `RemoteDispatcherImpl_Stub`-class is not missing. I found it at the correct position, but I could not find a `.java`-file with the same name.
Building and configuring the project works just fine. Only when executing `startpfbiz.sh` errors occure.

I've been looking for a solution in many forums and nothing worked for me. Does anyone of you have any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: It would have been easier if you have specified the version you use. Nevertheless I see you mention RMI in your tags. It could be that your problem is related with this Jira issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-6942 "Comment out RMI related code because of the Java deserialization issue [CVE-2016-2170] " please check

Comment: You won't find source code. It is a generated .class file. It is not in the 'correct position' as far as the RMI Registry is concerned, which is where the exception is coming from.